# Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError

Tags: wordpress, google-maps-api, google-maps

Перенес сайт (Wordpress) c поддомена на новый домен и перестала работать  Google карта. В консоли  Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError 
Но на старом поддомене все нормально работает. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: скорее всего проблема со стороны гугл мапс, видимо там, в настройках ключа, указана ссылка на ваш поддомен, нужно поменять на домен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я полагаю, дело в [Standard Plan Updates](https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/standard-plan-2016-update): "We no longer support keyless access (any request that doesn't include an API key)" для "All new domains or Developer Console API projects created on or after June 22, 2016".